# Disable top button on RibbonSplitButton

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

Is it possible to disable only the top button in a RibbonSplitButton?
If I set IsEnabled=True the entire button (top button plus drop down) is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do that.
If the top button is binded to a command, the canExecute of that command must be set to false.